# import <IOKit/IOMessage.h> gives error

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos

I'm using theos on iDevice. Installed it with installtheos3 command. If I got it right, it installed SDK too.
Now I have a project that has

```
import < IOKit/IOMessage.h >
```

Also I added IOKit to theos' makefile _FRAMEWORK section. Also I tried to add it to PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS section.

When I'm trying to 'make' i got this error:

```
error: IOKit/IOMessage.h: No such file or directory
```

there is no errors with other frameworks, only with this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons IOKit framework installed with 'installtheos3' doesn't have Headers directory at all. Copying it solved problem

Answer (score 0):

I never use theos, but this kind of error generally come from the `Header Search Path` option inside `Build Settings` inside your project settings.

Comment: I think if it was so, other frameworks wouldn't link then. I've just tried to add CFLAGS and OBJCFLAGS to make file with framework directories^ but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into similar issue, I had just downloaded files from [Github](https://github.com/nicolasgomollon/RecordScreen/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/IOKit) as part of my project and proceed forward.

Problem is, these header files are for C type of library(not really obj C). So I doubt, you would be able to include by changing path or config settings.